# Asp.net Web Api access restricting to specific website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

is it a good architecture practice to restrict a web Api call to a specific website by using referrer-url

will be there any security disadvantages with this approach, please guide on best practices if any (We not using Asp.net identity, which is completely custom authentication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring a specific [HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header is not a security measure, it is an obscurity measure. Any client who knows or intercepts this header will be able to call your API, the only difference is now it is *slightly* more difficult to build a working request.

Whether that is a strong enough security measure depends on your application requirements. If you are re-transmitting information that is already public through your WebApi, then it might be something to consider (along with HTTPS) just to avert DOS attacks on your API. If you are accepting user personal information, payment information, or making bank transfers, you clearly need additional security measures beyond this.